# How can docker-compose.yml include/omit environment-specific services?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way in docker-compose.yml to include a `db` service only in specific environments ("test" in my case)?

For a Ruby project, development and production both use a remote Postgres database, but the test needs it own local Postgres database.

What I have now is shown below... "works" in the sense that when we run in development the `db` container is simply ignored by our code (our dev't ENV supplies a remote postres url instead of using the `db` host). But it would be nicer to not spin up an unused docker container for `db` when running in development.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3010:3010"
    volumes:
      - .:/my_app
    links:
      - db.local
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:10.5
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Comment: You can specify multiple db images and do a conditional mount

Comment: You can write different compose files for different environments and name them as `docker-compose-local.yml`, `docker-compose-dev.yml` etc.. Then write a short shell script to choose between those files depending on the environment.